# How to send request with file in Android?

Tags: java, android, curl

I have a problem with sending CURL-like request with file.
Request in CURL looks like below:

`curl -k https://random-server.com -F "access_key=" -F "file=@file.xml"`

How to send exactly same request with file in Android?

Comment: Hi Patryk, what have you tried so far? What was the outcome? Please update your answer with those.

Comment: Use `curl --trace-ascii curl.trace ...` to see what curl does. Then search for it how to do it on Android.